# Assigning cell values to variables fails

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm writing a script for a google spreadsheet that should check to see whether the value of a particular cell is "Yes."  If so, it should just end.  If not, it should send an e-mail with the contents of several other cells to a defined address and write "Yes" to the designated cell.  However, the if condition in the code seems to always evaluate as true even when it should evaluate as false.  The script writes "Yes" to the designated cell and sends the e-mail.  However, while the e-mail contains the contents of the designated cells, it's all out of order.  Here's the script:

```
function sendNotification() {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,1,6);
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    var dateSubmitted = data[0];
    var dateDue = data[1];
    var url = data[2];
    var currentText = data[3];
    var newText = data[4];
    var emailSent = data[5];
    var test = 'Yes';
    var emailAddress = 'harland.westgate@gmail.com';
    var message = 'On ' + dateSubmitted + ' a colleague requested that ' + url + ' be changed to replace the text ' + currentText + ' with ' + newText + '.  This change should be completed by ' + dateDue;
    var subject = 'A website change has been requested';

    if (emailSent!=test) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
        sheet.getRange(2,6).setValue(test);
        // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
   }
}
```

The relevant cells are (sorry, tried to screenshot but rep is too low):

A2: 1/11/14
B2: 1/17/14
C2: www.google.com
D2: Lorem ipsum
E2: Dolor sit amit
F2: Yes

here's what it dumps into the body of the e-mail:

On Sat Jan 11 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST),Fri Jan 17 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST),www.google.com,Lorem ipsum,Dolor sit amit,Yes a colleague requested that undefined be changed to replace the text undefined with undefined.  This change should be completed by undefined

I've searched extensively and have not found an explanation for either behavior.  I don't think it's that the script is failing to read in the values of the cell range, because the e-mail body contains those values (just not where I was expecting them).  Then again, in the places I was expecting those values, it drops in "undefined."

Comment: I figured it out.  The array was created properly but I failed to account for the fact that data[#] looks at a row.  Therefore, my code dumped all of the one row read into the array into dateSubmitted, and the other variables were being assigned nothing.  The fix was to change the variable assignments to be =data[0][#] so that each one got one particular cell's worth of data.  [This page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#getValues()) set me straight.

Answer (score 0):

Remember [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues%28%29) returns a two-dimensional array of values.

Try:

```js
...
var dateSubmitted = data[0][0];
var dateDue = data[0][1];
var url = data[0][2];
...
```